# cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't run at all for tableview in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to write an app that will have a custom tableviewcell so i followed the apple developer sample code, but when i run my app, the screen is completely white.  When I put breakpoints/NSLogs in the numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection, or the cellForRowAtIndexPath, nothing shows.

Here is my delegate.m

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
rootViewController.displayList=[self displayList];
UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
self.navigationController=aNavigationController;
[aNavigationController release];
[rootViewController release];
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

And this is the cellForRowAtIndexPath in my RootViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
TableCell *tableCell = (TableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (tableCell == nil) {
    tableCell = [[[TableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    tableCell.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 60);
}

NSLog(@"71");
return tableCell;
```

}

I know that the cellForRowAtIndexPath won't show if there are no rows, but shouldn't the numberOfRowsInSection at least work? I even commented the numberOfRowsInSection out and the app was still able to build (still blank though)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you hook up the viewcontroller as the owner of the xib file? and then connect the datasource and delegate methods to the file owner?

EDIT: If you haven't created a xib file for your tableview, I recommend it over coding it out. After you create it, just connect everything like I mentioned. Also create one for your tableviewcell, and then load it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like either: datasource and delegates not hooked up. can be tested by

```
NSLog(@"%@,%@",tableView.delegate, tableView.datasource);
```

if they show up as null you have found your issue. 
if not that, then check for spelling mistakes in the delegate and datasource methods.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm not sure where to put the NSLog you wrote.  Putting it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath won't work since it's not being called, and putting it in the viewDidLoad won't build because it doesn't recognize tableView.  If I were to add a tableview from the XIB, would the delegate and datasource be set up already?

Comment: are you initialising from a nib, or are you creating the tableView in code? if you put it in viewDidLoad, and use self.tableView.delegate it should return. could I ask you to add the RootViewController header to your question please?